# conemu 2 shortcuts opening 2 set of tabs

Tags: conemu

My goal is to have 2 shortcuts (**shortcutA** and **shortcutB**).

When I double click on "**shortcutA**", then it launches conEmu and opens 3 tabs (tab1 in c:\folderA, tab2 in c:\folderB, tab3 in c:\folderC).

When I double click on "**shortcutB**", then it launches conEmu and opens 3 tabs (tab1 in c:\folderD, tab2 in c:\folderE, tab3 in c:\folderf).

I could create 2 tasks to open these folders. I'm using 2 different styles, I'm not sure which one is better:

TaskA:

> Task parameter:
> /dir "j:\folderA"
>
> > cmd.exe
>
> -new_console:d:c:\folderB
>
> -new_console:d:c:\folderC

And TaskB

> -new_console:d:c:\folderD
>
> -new_console:d:c:\folderE
>
> -new_console:d:c:\folderF

And for example the shortcut looks like that:

> C:\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe /cmd {TaskA}

When I double click on the shortcut, it opens 3 tabs but with this message:

> '{TaskA}' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Current directory:
> c:\folderA
>
> Command to be executed:
> "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /C {TaskA}
>
> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
> Press Enter or Esc to close console...

Could you tell me how to solve this issue?

Bonus question: is it possible to use a different background for the task? For example, if I double click on **shortcutA**, the background will be imageA (for the 3 tabs). If I double click on **shortcutB**, the background will be imageB (for the 3 tabs)

I'm using 140923.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have not specified the shells in your tasks. `-new_console` itself is just a switch,  but not a shell!

   ```
   > cmd
   cmd -new_console
   cmd -new_console
   ```
2. You can change background with -new_console. Have you read the wiki or description in the "About" dialog?

Comment: 1. yes (I will fix the typo in my message). 2. thanks, I will test with W.

Comment: Bad usage described

Comment: thank you. Exactly, I was missing "cmd" at the beginning